# How to map two consecutive Shift in Vim?

Tags: vim, macvim

Total vim newbie here, is there a way to map two consecutive `<Shift>` to execute `:FZF`? I try the following config in `.vimrc` but no luck

```
nmap <S><S> :FZF<Enter>
```

Comment: No. Vim doesn't see the Shift key at all so you can't map it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't atleast not without some serious hacking. To quote from the vim wiki

> Note that you cannot map the Shift or Alt or Ctrl keys alone as they
>   are key modifiers. You have to combine these key modifiers with other
>   keys to create a map.

[http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-*Tutorial*(Part_2)](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_(Part_2))

Also i'd recommend you use nnoremap rather than plain nmap, unless you explicitly want your map to be recursive.

On a  personal note i use the following mapping for :FZF which is basically a space followed by a 'f' in normal mode. I find it quite nice.

```
nnoremap <Leader>f :FZF
```

Happy Vimming.